# Delegate to a more specific Context Bound (additional implicit parameter)

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, circe, zio

I am trying to create an example of a ZIO Module, that has two implementations:

1. Using YAML with circe-yaml
2. Using HOCON with pureConfig

My general Interface looks like this:

```
trait Service[R] {
  def load[T <: Component](ref: CompRef): RIO[R, T]
}
```

Now my YAML implementation looks like:

```
def loadYaml[T <: Component: Decoder](ref: CompRef): RIO[Any, T] = {...}
```

The `Decoder` is implementation specific.

The problem is now how to delegate from the Service implementation to `loadYaml`.

I tried the following:

```
val components: Components.Service[Any] = new Components.Service[Any] {

  implicit val decodeComponent: Decoder[Component] =
      List[Decoder[Component]](
         Decoder[DbConnection].widen,
           ...
        ).reduceLeft(_ or _)

   def load[T <: Component](ref: CompRef): RIO[Any, T] = loadYaml[T] (ref)
}
```

This gives me:

```
Error:(62, 20) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type io.circe.Decoder[T]
       loadYaml[T] (ref)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I created an example project on Github: [zio-comps-module](https://github.com/pme123/zio-comps-module)

The idea is described here: [Decouple the Program from its Implementation with ZIO modules](https://medium.com/@pascal.mengelt/decouple-the-program-from-its-implementation-with-zio-modules-d9b8713d502e)

Comment: One option would be to create a new **typeclass** that abstracts over the `circe.Decoder` as well as the `pureconfig.ConfigReader` so it is only created for a type T if both implicits exists, then I would add that implicit to the general interface so it is passed down to the specific implementation, each implementation will just use the one it requires.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the suggestion. But the idea is that the interface has no knowledge of its implementation. Actually the next challenge would be to add a `zio-config` implementation.

Comment: Uhm, sorry I know nothing about **ZIO** _(and I have zero intention of doing so)_ So no idea if there are better ways. However, if you need an implicit you need to forward it up all the call stack. I still believe the idea of creating your own typeclass is the correct approach, maybe it relate somehow with that env thing zio always talks about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. All I had to do was to adjust the `load` function:

```
def load[T <: Component](ref: CompRef): RIO[ComponentsEnv, T] = {
  loadConf[Component](ref).map { case c: T => c }
}
```

First `loadConf` with the type `Component`.

Second cast result (`Component`) the the result type `T`.

This works but gives you ugly warnings:

```
[warn] /Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/zio-comps-module/hocon/src/pme123/zio/comps/hocon/HoconComps.scala:37:46: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]       loadConf[Component](ref).map { case c: T => c }
[warn]                                              ^
[warn] /Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/zio-comps-module/hocon/src/pme123/zio/comps/hocon/HoconComps.scala:37:36: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following inputs: DbConnection(_, _, _, _), DbLookup(_, _, _, _), MessageBundle(_, _)
[warn]       loadConf[Component](ref).map { case c: T => c }
[warn]                                    ^
[warn] two warnings found
```

**Update - I found a solution that get rid of the warnings:**

After reading the warning `unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` for the tenth time, I remembered that this could be solved with adding `ClassTag` as *Context Bound*.

The Service looks now

```
trait Service[R] {
  def load[T <: Component: ClassTag](ref: CompRef): RIO[R, T]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issues is that on the trait you have

```
def load[T <: Component]
```

and in the implementation u need

```
def loadYaml[T <: Component: Decoder]
```

then maybe you just need to parametrize `Decoder`

```
trait Service[R, D] {
  def load[T <: Component: D](ref: CompRef): RIO[R, T]
}
```

If there is no relation between the different type of `D` then you can define it as `Any` and then have the trait be `trait Service[R, +D]`.

Comment: thanks, but it does not work as the ContextBound is related to T which is defined on the function not the class. If you are motivated you can try yourself: https://github.com/pme123/zio-comps-module . Or let me know if you need a Bounty;).

Comment: You want to make `D` higher-kind for this context bound to make sense and for `Decoder` to be a possible `D`: `Service[R, D[_]]`.